# What is the max level in Zuma Blitz?

Tags: zumba-blitz

I heard rumors that the max level in the Facebook game Zuma Blitz is 80, and after that you can't gain any more levels or maybe even play anymore.

Could not find any official stuff about it, so I wonder if anyone here got to level 80 and can share what happens? Or what is the real max level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the maximum level in Zuma Blitz is indeed 80. After reaching that level, you can no longer level up. You CAN choose to become a "Zuma Master" and return to level 1, in exchange for a shiny gem on your Zuma Blitz profile.

This site details all of the levels in the game:
http://bchantech.blogspot.com/2010/12/zuma-blitz-level-up-table.html

Comment: Thanks, I saw that table but being year old wasn't sure it's up to date.

Comment: Don't worry, it's being regularly updated.

Comment: Note that this answer is for Zuma Blitz classic but the link now answers for Zuma Blitz Kroakatoa, which goes to level 400.